# How to clear an area from text with WriteConsoleOutputCharacter()?

Tags: c++, windows, output

So, I have a C++ class that represents rectangles, I use the `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter` function that outputs faster than `cout` or `printf()`, I've already made a program that prints the rectangle but I'm having trouble clearing the rectangle out.

From my understanding from msdn this function can print unicode characters or 8-bit characters from the console's current code page. Anyway, when I wanted to print backspace in order to clear the rectangle it didn't work and it prints something else(◘). When I tried to print backspace through it's hex code (0x008) it printed the symbol again.

The code is quite simple:

```
const char clr[] ="\b";//Thar the array I'm printing 


void rect_m::clr_ar()
{

    Ex = Vx + Lx;//These variables are the rectangle's sizes
    Ey = Vy + Ly;
    HANDLE mout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        //The loops cover the rectangle area
    for (SHORT i = Vy; i < Ey; i++)
    {
        for (SHORT j = Vx; j < Ex; j++)
        {
            WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(mout, clr, strlen(clr), { j,i }, &dwWritten);

        }
    }


}
```

Well, all I want is a way to print backspace with the `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter` function to clear the text out (and not by printing spaces over it). I know that's a very basic mistake and that there is a better way. So,can someone tell me please what's wrong with my code?

Comment: if you want clear some rectangle are - use `ScrollConsoleScreenBufferW`

Comment: Why are you specifically trying to print backspaces? A backspace is a non-printable character, and outside of interactive text entry it has nothing to do with removing characters. Why do you not want to overwrite characters with spaces?

Comment: and you need fill buffer with space `' '` instead "\b"

Comment: Look, It's not going to be the only one  rectangle that moves (yes,they can move),filling the gap with blank characters may cost some problems in the future, It's much easier to have empty space than blank characters.Anyway,If you have any better solution please let me know :)

Comment: for fill space with blank characters - use `ScrollConsoleScreenBufferW` - exactly this api use *cmd.exe* when you execute *cls* command

Comment: *have empty space than blank characters.*  - empty space is **equal to** blank characters

Answer (score 1):

for clear rectangle area we can use [`ScrollConsoleScreenBufferW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/scrollconsolescreenbuffer) for fill selected rectangle with blank characters. note that blank characters is equal to empty space, which we can view in test, if call `ReadConsoleOutputCharacter` at begin on yet empty console:

```
COORD xy{};
ULONG n;
WCHAR c;
ReadConsoleOutputCharacterW(hConsoleOutput, &c, 1, xy, &n);
//c == ' ';
```

so full code can look like:

```
BOOL cls(const SMALL_RECT* lpScrollRectangle = 0)
{
    HANDLE hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    if (GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsoleOutput, &csbi))
    {
        CHAR_INFO fi = { ' ', csbi.wAttributes };
        if (!lpScrollRectangle)
        {
            csbi.srWindow.Left = 0;
            csbi.srWindow.Top = 0;
            csbi.srWindow.Right = csbi.dwSize.X - 1;
            csbi.srWindow.Bottom = csbi.dwSize.Y - 1;
            lpScrollRectangle = &csbi.srWindow;
        }
        return ScrollConsoleScreenBufferW(hConsoleOutput, lpScrollRectangle, 0, csbi.dwSize, &fi);
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't really know how call\use this function for cleaning my rectangle :| ,I do have the rectangle's corners coordinates if that helps you...  I'm quite new to these windows functions...

Comment: @Gelgavish - but in what problem ? fill `SMALL_RECT sr;` structure and call `cls(&sr)` for clear concrete rectangle. or call `cls()` for clear all screen buffer